# Liferay : saxReaderUtil Results

Tags: liferay-6, saxparser, liferay-velocity

While fetching results from Liferay web content articles, using SAX reader and Velocity , the number of results is limited to 5!

$saxReaderUtil.readURL("http://$request.theme-display.url-portal/c/journal/get_articles?groupId=10157&type=typeOne&approved=true&orderBy=display-date

How can I fetch all the elements?

I'm Using Liferay 6.0.6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Adding delta parameter.
$saxReaderUtil.readURL("http://$request.theme-display.url-portal/c/journal/get_articles?groupId=10157&type=typeOne&approved=true&orderBy=display-date&**delta**=100");
Here, the request will bring 100 results.